# Restaurar tamanho da UL ao deixar o foco!

Tags: jquery, css, css3

Tenho o **código** abaixo:

```js
$("ul#menu > li").find("label").hover ( function(e) {
  
  e.stopPropagation();
  
  let ul = $(this).parent().find("ul");
  
  ul.css('display', e.type == "mouseenter" ? 'flex' : 'none');
  
 });
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color 1s;
}
label {
 display: inline-block;
}

body section#menu > div.internas {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center; 
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul {
 display: flex;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > * {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 width: 200px;
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > label {
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 50px;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > ul> li > a : hover {
 background: #999;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > ul> li > a {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 height: 50px;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > ul {
 display: none;
 flex-direction: column;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > a:hover {
 background: #999;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="menu">
 
 <div class="internas">
  
  <ul id="menu">
  
   <li>
    <label>Cadastrar</label>
    <ul id="menuCadastrar">
     <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/administradores">Administradores</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/cursos">Cursos</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/fornecedores">Fornecedores</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/tecnicos">Técnicos</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/youtubers">Youtubers</a></li>
    </ul>
      </li>
  
   <li>
    <label>Editar</label>
    <ul id="menuEditar">
     <li><a href="/admin/editar/administradores">Administradores</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/editar/cursos">Cursos</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/editar/fornecedores">Fornecedores</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/editar/tecnicos">Técnicos</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/editar/youtubers">Youtubers</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   
  </ul>
  
 </div>
 
</section>
```

O **problema** é que, como o **código** *manda*, ao *passar* o  **mouse** na **LI**, a **UL** interna aparece. De fato aparece!

Mas me esbarro no fato que ao me dirigir com o **mouse** para a **UL** interna eu deixo a **LI** da **UL** principal e perco o foco fechando a **UL** interna!

Alguma dica mais oficial?

Como vocês costumam fazer?

**EDIÇÃO**:

Fiz um teste aumentando o tamanho da **li** mas mesmo assim, ao sair do **focus**, ela não respeita o tamanho da **LI**

```js
$("ul#menu > li").find("label").hover ( function(e) {
 
 e.stopPropagation();
 
 let ul = $(this).parent().find("ul");
 
 let qtdeLi = ul.parent().find("li").length;
 
 let altUl = qtdeLi * 50;
 
 $(this).parent().css('height', e.type == "mouseenter" ? altUl : 50);
 
 ul.css('display', e.type == "mouseenter" ? 'flex' : 'none');
 
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color 1s;
}
label {
 display: inline-block;
}

body section#menu > div.internas {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center; 
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul {
 display: flex;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > * {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 width: 200px;
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > label {
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 50px;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > ul> li > a : hover {
 background: #999;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > ul> li > a {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 height: 50px;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > ul {
 display: none;
 flex-direction: column;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > a:hover {
 background: #999;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="menu">
 
 <div class="internas">
  
  <ul id="menu">
  
   <li>
    <label>Cadastrar</label>
    <ul id="menuCadastrar">
     <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/administradores">Administradores</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/cursos">Cursos</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/fornecedores">Fornecedores</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/tecnicos">Técnicos</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/youtubers">Youtubers</a></li>
    </ul>
      </li>
  
   <li>
    <label>Editar</label>
    <ul id="menuEditar">
     <li><a href="/admin/editar/administradores">Administradores</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/editar/cursos">Cursos</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/editar/fornecedores">Fornecedores</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/editar/tecnicos">Técnicos</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/editar/youtubers">Youtubers</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   
  </ul>
  
 </div>
 
</section>
```

Depois da explicação do colega Hugo, inclusive me puxando a orelha com razão, kkk, fiz outra tentativa.

Mas, Hugo, por favor, não me entenda mal. Eu não gosto de copiar códigos prontos. Acho mais importante entender que copiar.

Fiz outra tentativa seguinte sua resposta mas ainda continuo com o mesmo problema de perder a UL ao sair da li.

```css
  body section#menu > div.internas {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul {
display: flex;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > label {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
cursor: pointer;
border: 1px solid #CCC;

}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > label:hover {
background: #CCC;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > label:hover + ul {
display: flex;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > ul  {
display: none;
flex-direction: column;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > ul > li > a  {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
height: 50px;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
padding-left: 5px;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover  {
background: #CCC;
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
   <section id="menu">

<div class="internas">
 
 <ul>
 
  <li>
   <label>Cadastrar</label>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/administradores">Administradores</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/cursos">Cursos</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/fornecedores">Fornecedores</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/tecnicos">Técnicos</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/youtubers">Youtubers</a></li>
   </ul>
     </li>
 
  <li>
   <label>Editar</label>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="/admin/editar/administradores">Administradores</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/editar/cursos">Cursos</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/editar/fornecedores">Fornecedores</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/editar/tecnicos">Técnicos</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/editar/youtubers">Youtubers</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  
 </ul>
 
</div>

</section>
```

Onde errei dessa vez?

Comment: Legal que vc chegou a um resultado satisfatório, valeu a  força

Comment: #tmjjuntosempre, eu que agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara já te falei, vc precisa para e estudar um pouco CSS. Vc está repetindo dois `IDs` iguais em dois elementos diferentes. Está criando classes com concatenações desnecessária e sem sentido tipo `body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > ul`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E para finalizar se problema nem precisa de jQuery para resolver, só com CSS resolve, o que acontece é que vc tem que dar `display:flex` no `UL` do *sub-menu* quando vc fizar `:hover` na `LI` pai dessa `UL` *sub-menu*, só isso.

```css
#menuX > li:hover ul {
    display: flex !important;
}


ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color 1s;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
}

body section#menu > div.internas {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

body section#menu > div.internas > ul {
    display: flex;
align-items: flex-start;
}

body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > * {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > label {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 50px;
}

body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > ul > li > a : hover {
    background: #999;
}

body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > ul > li > a {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 50px;
}

body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
}

body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > a:hover {
    background: #999;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<section id="menu">

<div class="internas">

    <ul id="menuX">

        <li>
            <label>Cadastrar</label>
            <ul id="menuCadastrar">
                <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/administradores">Administradores</a></li>
                <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/cursos">Cursos</a></li>
                <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/fornecedores">Fornecedores</a></li>
                <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/tecnicos">Técnicos</a></li>
                <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/youtubers">Youtubers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label>Editar</label>
            <ul id="menuEditar">
                <li><a href="/admin/editar/administradores">Administradores</a></li>
                <li><a href="/admin/editar/cursos">Cursos</a></li>
                <li><a href="/admin/editar/fornecedores">Fornecedores</a></li>
                <li><a href="/admin/editar/tecnicos">Técnicos</a></li>
                <li><a href="/admin/editar/youtubers">Youtubers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Com a *ajuda* do *colega* **Hugo**, consegui fazer a minha **própria solução** de forma que eu consiga entender.

Mas pela ajuda dele, aceitei a sua reposta como **satisfatória**.

No entanto, quero deixar minha **colaboração**!

```css
* {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
}
body {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; /*Comprimir(diminuir) as medidas do elemento para não aumentá-lo quando adicinar margin e padding*/
}
body > section {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 width: 100vw;
}
body > section > div {
 display: flex;
 width: 1200px;
 padding: 10px;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color 1s;
}
label {
 display: inline-block;
}
body section#menu > div.internas {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
 padding-bottom: 300px;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul {
    display: flex;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > label {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 width: 200px;
 height: 50px;
 cursor: pointer;
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
 
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > label:hover {
 background: #CCC;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > ul  {
    display: none;
 flex-direction: column;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li:hover ul {
 position: absolute;
    display: flex;
 z-index: 100;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > ul > li > a  {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 width: 200px;
 height: 50px;
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
 padding-left: 5px;
}
body section#menu > div.internas > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover  {
 background: #CCC;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section id="menu">
 
 <div class="internas">
  
  <ul>
  
   <li>
    <label>Cadastrar</label>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/administradores">Administradores</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/cursos">Cursos</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/fornecedores">Fornecedores</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/tecnicos">Técnicos</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/cadastrar/youtubers">Youtubers</a></li>
    </ul>
      </li>
  
   <li>
    <label>Editar</label>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="/admin/editar/administradores">Administradores</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/editar/cursos">Cursos</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/editar/fornecedores">Fornecedores</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/editar/tecnicos">Técnicos</a></li>
     <li><a href="/admin/editar/youtubers">Youtubers</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   
  </ul>
  
 </div>
 
</section>
```

Obrigado!